# Is it possible to hide a UITableView's rows but not the search bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UITable with a UISearchBar

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 44)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

The 'hidden' attribute hides the entire table, including the search bar.

`self.tableView.hidden = false;`

Is there any simple way to hide the rows of the table, but not the search bar? I want to show another UIView when the search returns no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is when there are no results, so number of rows = 0, I instead return 1 row.  This row is a UITableViewCell that is your empty screen.  So, you should calculate the height of your UITableView and subtract the search view height from it.  This height is your "Search is empty" view height.

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

1. Use `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`
2. Add `tableView` (leave 44px from top)
3. Add `Searchbar` on the top of all, (not in `TableView`)

Now you are good to go.

Comment: It's a horrible way to go!  iOS standard UIs have the search bar embedded in the tableview so it scrolls out of the way when the user scrolls up.  Why don't you have a UISearchController managing your search?

Comment: @Avi What is so horrible about it. Please be technically specific. Considering, question specifically state the requirement is to not hide the `searchBar`.

Comment: @rptwsthi, thanks again for your answer, had to unaccept because I ended up going with solution suggested in the answer below -- was easier for me to implement and fit better into what I already had.

Comment: @Avi just a personal implementation choice not to use UISearchController. as far as I can tell I don't really need it and it makes my life easier as I have to support older versions of iOS.